# How may I convert a three-digit Arabic number (Perl [0-9][0-9][0-9]) to a three-digit English representation ([zero-nine][zero-nine][zero-nine])

Tags: latex, numeric-conversion

The alternative is to use Roman numerals, for which a package is
available.  I am using the LaTeX catchfile package and the \input{}
command to associate a title in a set of TITLE files with \section{}
commands in a set of DOCUMENT files.

I would like to have a file of catchfile definitions, with records
such as:

```
\CatchFileDef{\t-001}{title-001.tex}{}

\CatchFileDef{\t-002}{title-002.tex}{}

\CatchFileDef{\t-003}{title-003.tex}{}

But LaTeX does not allow numerical labels such as "\title-003".

Roman numerals are workable:

\CatchFileDef{\ti}{title-001.tex}{}

\CatchFileDef{\tii}{title-002.tex}{}

\CatchFileDef{\tiii}{title-003.tex}{}

but are ugly in comparison with:

\CatchFileDef{\tzerozeroone}{title-001.tex}{}

\CatchFileDef{\tzerozerotwo}{title-002.tex}{}

\CatchFileDef{\tzerozerothree}{title-003.tex}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

On possibility to convert digits into their corresponding words is the `numspell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numspell}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {0,...,9}{
\foreach \y in {0,...,9}{
\foreach \z in {0,...,9}{

\x\y\z : \numspell{\x}\numspell{\y}\numspell{\z}

}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If only I could run three instances of numspell in parallel!  I envision a one-time effort to generate a look-up table of, say, a thousand entries,  Perhaps manual editing would be most economical.  After all, the range of numbers is only zero to nine.

Comment: @russ what's stopping you from call numspell multiple times?

Comment: I did not see just how to do it.  I envisioned a list with items <\zerozeroone> to <\nineninenine>; catchfile uses the list to associate document files with files <title-001> to <title-999>.  A couple of hours editing with Emacs seemed to me to be the most simple solution.  At least now when I am working on file 684, it is easy to remember the key, which is <\sixeightfour>; in Roman that is <DCLXXXIV>, except on my wall clock <4> is <IIII> rather than <IV>.

Comment: @russ so nest 3 loops from 0 to 9?

Comment: Yes.  I know how to use Emacs to produce a series of Arabic numbers, so cut and paste was needed only for the English spellings zero, one, two, three, ... , nine.   Actually I did only three hundred, but it would be nice to learn how to automate the process.

Answer (score -1):

In an hour or two, using Emacs, I created a look up table which solved the problem.  The English spelling of Arabic numerals appears to be less prone to error than is the use of Roman numerals.